# Android - Cordova/PhoneGap - Keyboard Shows on Load & on Resume from Background

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Cordova (3.3.0)/PhoneGap application I am building.

I am having several issues with the keyboard showing in the Android version (issue does not occur on iOS):

- All devices, the keyboard shows during load, but then hides when the app inits
- Some devices (Nexus 5 in particular), the keyboard does not hide on init
- Some devices (again, Nexus 5), the keyboard also shows when the app resumes from background, even if the keyboard was previously hidden

Any insight to why this might be?

I have the following value in my config.xml (in the root www folder):

```
<preference value="true" name="KeyboardShrinksView"/>
```

Some other info that might be relevant:

- I am using the cordova CLI to build my project
- I am using a few plugins, namely: device, dialogs, inappbrowser, network-information
- I do have one input control (textbox) on one of my 'pages' in the background (a separate `<div>` to avoid confusion), but as far as I can tell, this input does not gain focus.  I have confirmed this with javascript alerts.

Thank you in advance for your time and efforts!

Comment: Did you check the cordova.js/phonegap.js it's referenced in your HTML, and if it is on the correct location in the android sources

Comment: Yes, cordova.js is referenced in my html page, `deviceready` fires correctly, and the app's other capabilities work great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to fix my own bug.
It had to do with the AndroidManifest.xml configuration, and not anything Cordova/Phonegap related.  Specifically the

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

attribute on the activity declaration.  I can't remember where I found the suggestion for `stateVisible`, but I believe it was leftover from working through some other keyboard issues.  I adjusted the value to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

and it fixed the problem.